# HTTPHandler tag in Web.Config breaks asmx Files

Tags: asp.net, web-services, configuration, web-config, httphandler

In my ASP.Net 1.1 application, i've added the following to my Web.Config (within the System.Web tag section):

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add verb="*" path="*.bcn" type="Internet2008.Beacon.BeaconHandler, Internet2008" />
</httpHandlers>
```

This works fine, and the HTTPHandler kicks in for files of type .bcn, and does its thing.. however for some reason all ASMX files stop working.  Any idea why this would be the case?

Cheers
Greg

Answer (score 3):

I got it... CQ you were on the right track.. i did need to add the .asmx handler again, but the .net 1.1 specific one.  Final code is as follows:

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add verb="*" path="*.bcn" type="Internet2008.Beacon.BeaconHandler, Internet2008" validate="false" />
  <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" type="System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory, System.Web.Services, Version=1.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" validate="false"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

I hope there's no other file types that are not getting handled properly because of this declaration.  :|

Thanks for the help
greg

Comment: Woohoo, okay yeah sorry I didn't have the full path, but i'm really glad you got it working!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like it as an inherant <clear /> in it although I don't know if I've seen this behaviour before, you could just add the general handler back, let me find you the code.

```
<add verb="*" path="*.asmx" type="System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory, System.Web.Services" validate="false">
```

I think thats the right element, give it a shot.

EDIT: That is odd, I don't have a copy of 2003 on this machine so I can't open a 1.1 but I thought that was the right declaration.  You could try adding `validate="false"` into each element and see if that makes a difference.